# What is the correct method to locate and throw away unnecessary files when your disk is full on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, filesystems

Looking the size of each file in your system manually in order to find the bottlenecks is, obviously, too inefficient. What is the correct way to have a good overview of which files are consuming most of the resources of your disk, in order to decide which ones to discard?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if the content is user created—meaning items you have created or software you installed—you—via hunting and pecking—are the only real “tool” to clean up unwanted items.

But if your system seems sluggish or has bottlenecks, your best bet is to use a cache cleaning tool like [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/downloadonyx.php). It’s fairly simple to use and allows to you safely deeply clean caches on man different versions of Mac OS X.

> OnyX is a multifunction utility for OS X which allows you to verify
>   the startup disk and the structure of its system files, to run
>   miscellaneous tasks of system maintenance, to configure some hidden
>   parameters of the Finder, Dock, QuickTime, Safari, Mail, iTunes, login
>   window, Spotlight, and many of Apple’s applications, to delete caches,
>   to remove a certain number of files and folders that may become
>   cumbersome, and more.